# output collection type in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony4

I am trying to display the collection in the editor for users, but I'm getting the following error:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class
> App\Entity\Role, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by
> setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view
> transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of
> App\Entity\Role.

**Controller method**

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="admin_edit_assign_roles")
 */
public function edit(Request $request, User $user){
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_assign_roles');
    }

    return $this->render('admin/assign_roles/edit.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

**AssignRolesType.php**

```
class AssignRolesType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name');
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Role::class
    ]);
}

}
```

**UserType.php**

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('email');
    $builder->add('roles', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => AssignRolesType::class,
        'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
    ]);
}

function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => User::class
    ]);
}
}
```

**Entity\User.php**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 */

class User implements UserInterface
{
private $prefix = "ROLE_";

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

//    /**
//     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
//     */
//    private $roles = [];


/**
 * @var Collection|Role[]
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Role")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="user_roles",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $roles;

/**
 * @var string The hashed password
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $isVerified = false;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $vkontakteID;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $vkontakteAccessToken;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $lastName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
 */
private $nickName;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}


public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(string $email): self
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * A visual identifier that represents this user.
 *
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getUsername(): string
{
    return (string) $this->email;
}

/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getRoles(): array
{
    foreach ($this->roles->toArray() as $roleItem){
        $roles[] = $this->prefix . $roleItem->getSlug();
    }

    // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    return array_unique($roles);
}

public function setRoles(Collection $roles): self
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}

public function addRole(Role $role){
    $this->roles->add($role);
}

public function removeRole(Role $role){
    $this->roles->removeElement($role);
}

/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getPassword(): string
{
    return (string) $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
}

/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
    // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
    // $this->plainPassword = null;
}

public function isVerified(): bool
{
    return $this->isVerified;
}

public function setIsVerified(bool $isVerified): self
{
    $this->isVerified = $isVerified;

    return $this;
}

public function getVkontakteID(): ?int
{
    return $this->vkontakteID;
}

public function setVkontakteID(?int $vkontakteID): self
{
    $this->vkontakteID = $vkontakteID;

    return $this;
}

public function getFirstName(): ?string
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

public function setFirstName(?string $firstName): self
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;

    return $this;
}

public function getLastName(): ?string
{
    return $this->lastName;
}

public function setLastName(?string $lastName): self
{
    $this->lastName = $lastName;

    return $this;
}

public function getNickName(): ?string
{
    return $this->nickName;
}

public function setNickName(string $nickName): self
{
    $this->nickName = $nickName;

    return $this;
}

public function getVkontakteAccessToken(): ?string
{
    return $this->vkontakteAccessToken;
}

public function setVkontakteAccessToken(?string $vkontakteAccessToken): self
{
    $this->vkontakteAccessToken = $vkontakteAccessToken;

    return $this;
}

public function getIsVerified(): ?bool
{
    return $this->isVerified;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

#### Reason for your error message

Your `User.getRoles()` returns an array of strings.
Your `UserType`'s roles' `CollectionType` field has entry type `AssignRoleType`, which expects `Role` entities. The form accesses the property via getter, if one exists, and that getter (`getRoles`) only returns an array of strings, which the `CollectionType` provides to the `AssignRoleType`s, which obviously complain about the string not being a `Role` entity.

Since you're probably using the Symfony security roles system, `getRoles` probably has to return strings. So changing that is essentially out of the question.

#### renaming for profit

the following approach isn't really that elegant, but it's simple. The form component doesn't care how the properties on the User class are called, it only cares about access(ors).

You could implement the methods `getRoleObjects`, `addRoleObject`, `removeRoleObject` (the latter two should be identical to `addRole` and `removeRole`) on `User` and rename the form field to `role_objects`, and then you should be golden. The `getRoleObjects` would have to `return $this->roles->toArray()`, after that everything should work fine.

#### comment

You probably want `EntityType` (with the `multiple` option set to `true`) *instead* of the `CollectionType`, unless you really want to edit the roles' names. But just guessing here. What do I know, right?! ^^

The approach with the different name isn't particularly nice, there are other options like using datatransformers for this particular use case, which could work nicely.

Comment: you could use a [data transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) that either takes your list of strings and turn them *back* into Role objects, or a model transformer, that resolves the roles field by calling a different function on user to get the role entities.